# obtener de un array/objeto multidimensional el numero de caracteres de la llave(key) con mayor numero de caracteres

Tags: php, array, refactoring

estoy tratando de obtener de un array/objeto multidimensional el numero de caracteres de la llave(key) con mayor numero de caracteres:

*(por ahora solo he probado con array):*

**Metodo:**

```
function findHighKeySize($array, $cz = 0)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (strlen($key) > $cz) {
                    $cz = strlen($key);
                }
                $cz = findHighKeySize($value, $cz);
            } else {
                if (strlen($key) > $cz) {
                    $cz = strlen($key);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (strlen($array) > $cz) {
            $cz = strlen($array);
        }
        return $cz;
    }
}
```

**el array de prueba:**

```
class FooBar
{
    function foo_function()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

$var_class = new FooBar;

$example_single = true;

$example_array = [
    'null'         => null,
    'null_text'    => 'null',
    'integer'      => 10,
    'integer_text' => '10',
    'float'        => 20.35,
    'float_text'   => '20.35',
    'string'       => 'Hello World',
    'date_1'       => '2021-01-17',
    'date_2'       => '2021-Jan-17',
    'hour_1'       => '6:31:00 AM',
    'hour_2'       => '17:31:00',
    'datetime_1'   => '2021-01-17 17:31:00',
    'datetime_2'   => '2021-Jan-17 6:31:00 AM',
    'datetime_3'   => '2021-01-17 6:31:00 AM',
    'datetime_4'   => '2021-Jan-17 17:31:00',
    'currency_1'   => '1.45$',
    'currency_2'   => '$ 1.45',
    'array'        => [
        'boolean_true'       => true,
        'boolean_false'      => false,
        'boolean_true_text'  => 'true',
        'boolean_false_text' => 'false',
    ],
    'objects_list' => [
        'object'   => (object) [],
        'class'    => $var_class,
        'resource' => curl_init(),
    ],
];

$example_array['array']['nested'] = ['other' => (object) ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']];
```

pero no me devuelve nada (ni error).

***Update***

Intente con array walk recursive:

```
$counter = 0;

array_walk_recursive($example_array, function ($value, $key, $counter) {
    if (strlen($key) > $counter) {
        $counter = strlen($key);
    }
    return $counter;
}, $counter);


echo $counter;
```

y me devuelve: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Esta es una Respuesta Parcial para los `Arrays` y `Objetos`:**

la manera correcta de hacerlo es empleando el método nativo `array_walk_recursive`:

```
array_walk_recursive($example_array, function (&$value, $key) {
    if (is_object($value)) {
        $value = (array) $value;
    }
});

$counter = ['key' => 0, 'val' => 0];

array_walk_recursive($example_array, function ($value, $key) use (&$counter) {
    $counter['key'] = ($counter['key'] >= strlen($key)) ? $counter['key'] : strlen($key);
    if (!is_array($value) && !is_object($value) && !is_resource($value)) {
        $counter['val'] = ($counter['val'] >= strlen($value)) ? $counter['val'] : strlen($value);
    }
}, $counter);

echo 'Contador final key: ' . $counter['key'];
echo '<br>';
echo 'Contador final val: ' . $counter['val'];
```

Esto hará un recorrido de todos los elementos del array/objeto y su respectiva verificación, convirtiendo los objetos en arrays.

***Tengo pendiente hacer la verificación en caso de que la variable sea no sea objeto ni array como obtener la cantidad de caracteres del nombre de la variable.***

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir una variable que contenga el nombre del último índice más largo al anterior que se encontró e ir actualizándolo comparando con `strlen`

```
function getLongKey($array) {
    $lastLong = "";
    foreach($array as $el => $v)  {
        if (strlen($el) > strlen($lastLong)) {
            $lastLong = $el;
        }
    }
    return $lastLong;
}
```

Lo que hace es recorrer el array, obteniendo el elemento y el valor (último dato que no usaremos), y tenemos la variable `$lastLong`, por cada elemento, compararemos la longitud de `$lasLong` y la longitud del elemento actual, si es mayor la del elemento actual, reasignaremos `$lastLong`

---

Podemos recorrer arrays anidados, definiendo una función que recoja todos los *keys*, dentro de otro array, de manera que tenemos un solo array con todos los keys del array principal y de los arrays anidados

```
function array_flat($array) {
    $arr = [];
    foreach($array as $el => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach(array_keys($v) as $nv) {
                if (is_array($nv)) {
                    array_push($arr, array_values(array_flat($nv)));
                } else {
                    array_push($arr, $nv);
                }
            }
        } else {
            array_push($arr, $el);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Entonces, simplemente usamos la otra función

```
print(getLongKey(array_flat($example_array)));
```

Resultado:

```
boolean_false_text
```

---

Y finalmente, lo he resuelto con `array_walk_recursive`

```
function array_flat_recursive($a) {
    $r = [];
    foreach(array_keys($a) as $k) {
        array_push($r, $k);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($a, function ($value, $key) use (&$r){
      $r[] = $key;
  }, $r);
  return $r;
}
```

Comment: no soporta el tema de que sea multidimensional; he actualizado la pregunta por que intente implementar array walk recursive

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Probé exactamente con el array que pusiste y el resultado fue `integer_text` con esta función

Comment: Por otro lado puede ser que quisieras obtener el mayor length de los keys de cada array anidado y del array principal ¿Es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: busco el numero de caracteres que tiene la llave con mayor length de todo el array/objeto en este caso creo que seria `boolean_false_text` y deberia de devolver un `18`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Entiendo. Estoy trabajando en ello

Comment: el otro problema con el que me acabo de encontrar es que pasa si la variable no es un array... pero igual quisiera obtener la cantidad de caracteres que tiene el nombre original XD

Comment: para este ultimo escenario creo que tendria que usar reflection pero ni idea como se mastica XD

Comment: solucione la parte de los arrays pero ni idea de como hacerlo con objetos y si no es un array como hacerlo con variables: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/430184/46896

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Lamento llegar tan tarde, tuve que atender algo, pero tengo una forma que lo puede resolver, en seguida la añado

Comment: ya verifique la nueva idea pero esta limitado a un array de 2 dimensiones ... y aunque el ejemplo es de 2 dimensiones; se espera resolver un array u objeto multidimensional.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Ese no es problema, podemos comprobar si es array y llamar a la función la cual hará un foreach así hasta que no haya arrays restantes

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120044/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-and-anythingg).